# Hartree Fock Feynman diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, feynman

I am trying to reproduce the Feynman graph of the Hartree-Fock self energy, composed of two term (exchange and Coulomb), as in the figure:

[image]

I have tried the code below, the second term is ok, but I am still half way to get something decent for the first term. How come I am not able to fix points c on the same axis as a-b and c-d on its orthogonal, in the position above?

Can anyone suggest how to put the bubble in the right position and put arrows on it?
Any other suggestion is welcomed.

Many thanks

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman,contour}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\coordinate (a);
\coordinate[left=1cm of a] (b);
\coordinate[left=1cm of b] (c);
\coordinate[top=1.0cm of c] (d);
\diagram* {
a --[fermion] b[dot];
b --[photon] d;
b --[fermion] c;
};
\end{feynman}
\draw[arc arrow={to pos 0.1 with length 2mm}] (d) arc(0:360:0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{feynman}
\coordinate (a);
\coordinate[left=1cm of a] (b);
\coordinate[left=2.0cm of b] (c);
\coordinate[left=4.0cm of a] (d);
\diagram* {
a -- b[dot] -- [photon, half left] c[dot] -- d,
b -- [fermion] c };
\end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you make a complete example containing all necessary styles? `arc arrow` isn't a standard style, and I'd also think `top` should be `above`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Sebastiano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117876/sebastiano?tab=profile)'s answer and on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193647/188118), I could get a better, yet not complete, result.
[image]
I had to:

- compile with lulatex
- remove the `feynman` environment from within `tikzpicture`
- I defined a `photon1/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=black}` style in `\tikzset` (I tried to modify wave amplitude=0.3mm and wave count=10 but I could not get these equal to the `photon` style).

I still need to:

- make the two photons look the same
- rotate the bubble and align it on top of the photon edge (I now added another point `e`, probably one can fix it just with the right option on `d`)
- add two arrows to the bubble

Below there is the updated version of the code.

Thank you

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,positioning,automata,backgrounds,calc,er,patterns}
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\tikzfeynmanset{compat=1.1.0}

% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160358/21344; changed photon style
\tikzset{
  fermion/.style={draw=black, postaction={decorate},decoration={markings,mark=at position .55 with {\arrow{Latex}}}},
  vertex/.style={draw,shape=circle,fill=black,minimum size=2pt,inner sep=0pt},
  photon/.style={wavy semicircle,wave amplitude=0.3mm,wave count=10},
  photon1/.style={decorate, decoration={snake}, draw=black}
}

% adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89003/21344; swapped atan args
\newif\ifmirrorsemicircle
\tikzset{
    wave amplitude/.initial=0.2cm,
    wave count/.initial=8,
    mirror semicircle/.is if=mirrorsemicircle,
    mirror semicircle=false,
    wavy semicircle/.style={
        to path={
            let \p1 = (\tikztostart),
            \p2 = (\tikztotarget),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\x1)},
            \n2 = {atan2(\x2-\x1,\y2-\y1))} in
            plot [
                smooth,
                samples=(\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave count}+0.5)*8+1, % Calculate the number of samples needed, so the samples are in sync with the wave and fall on the extrema
                domain=0:1,
                shift={($(\p1)!0.5!(\p2)$)}
            ] ({ % Polar coordinates: Angle...
                (\x*180-\n2 + 180 + \ifmirrorsemicircle 1 \else -1 \fi * 90%
            }:{ % ... and radius
                (%
                    \n1/2+\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave amplitude} * %
                    sin(
                        \x * 360 * (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/wave count} + 0.5%
                    )%
                )%
            })
        } (\tikztotarget)
    }
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (i);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of i] (v1);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of v1] (v2);
\coordinate[right=of v2] (o);
\draw (i) -- (v1);
\draw[fermion] (v1) -- (v2);
\draw[photon] (v1) to (v2);
\draw (v2) -- (o);
\end{tikzpicture}
+
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of a] (b);
\coordinate[vertex, right=of b] (c);
\coordinate[vertex, above=of b] (d);
\coordinate[vertex, above=of d] (e);
\draw [fermion] (a) -- (b);
\draw [fermion] (b) -- (c);
\draw [photon1] (b) to (d);
\draw [arc arrow={to pos 0.0 with length 1mm}] (e) arc(0:360:0.4);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much also because you have put my name. Regards from the Sicily.

Answer (score 0):

This is an half answer: your original drawing has been built with [`feynMF`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/feynmf/fmfman.pdf) package.
`feynMF` use METAFONT (or METAPOST).

Here can you see an example to pag. 30 where there is the same loop with the arrows. It is an old package of the 1996.

[image]

Now I suggest to see this link: [Tikz, decorations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193462/tikz-decorations) or [Package for typesetting Feynman diagrams (efficiency of `feynmp` and `tikz`)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86588/package-for-typesetting-feynman-diagrams-efficiency-of-feynmp-and-tikz) where it is used for the Feynman diagrams:
`TikZ-Feynman` package.

**ADDENDUM:** If you prefer to be a flash to draw your image it is possible to use [FeynGame](https://gitlab.com/feyngame/FeynGame) a tool in Java for drawing Feynman diagrams only for Linux and MacOS.