# Feynman diagrams: curved arrow to use into feyn package

Tags: macros, symbols, packages, feynman, feynmp

I wanted to draw the same figure of this question [Hartree Fock Feynman diagrams](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553705/hartree-fock-feynman-diagrams) using `feyn` package:

[image]

The curved arrow are specific of `feynmp` package for me complicated because I have not understood many commands and the style of this package.

[image]

I'm not able to draw the circle with curved arrow like the first picture.

> Is there a possibility using `feyn` package?

Comment: It seems like Section 6 in this PDF should get you the answer: http://osksn2.hep.sci.osaka-u.ac.jp/~taku/osx/feynmp/fmfsamples.pdf

Comment: @cbishop Thank you very much much for your reply. See my question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553705/hartree-fock-feynman-diagrams/553738#553738. I know your file pdf :-)

Comment: Oops! Sorry about that! I should have read more carefully :-) My fault for jumping into a question on a package/area that I don't work with. I think I found a not-perfect solution with \feyn that I have added below.

Comment: @cbishop ahahaha..no...don't worry about it. With me no problems. :-)

Comment: Congratulations on your 30.000 points!

Comment: @AndréC Thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu to you and to all users......... Just in this moment I was playing the Burning heart (Survivor) guitar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a hacky attempt on my part so I am sure you can improve on it, but

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{feyn, graphicx}

\begin{document}

$\Diagram{& \ \, {\rotatebox{80}{$\feyn{a}$}}\!c\!^{\rotatebox{-105}{$\feyn{a}$}} & \\
  \mbox{$\Sigma_{HF}(\mathbf{p}, \omega) = $ } & fs gv fs \ + \ fglS a f }$

\end{document}
```

[image: Attempt using \feyn and \rotatebox]

Also, as a side note: It seems like the `\feyn` package does some weird things with how you center rotations with `\rotatebox`. It generally ignores the `[origin = ]` command. If you want to rotate an arrow like `\feyn{a}` and keep it roughly on the same line you actually need to add a phantom object, so something like `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\feyn{a}$\phantom{a}}` gets the job done better than `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{$\feyn{a}$}`. (Kind of weird, but I am sure the answer is buried somewhere in the package itself.)

---

I moved the arrows a little bit vertically using the `\raisebox` command. (Turns out I was using it wrong or this would have been my original answer.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{feyn, graphicx}

\begin{document}

$\Diagram{& \ \, \raisebox{.5mm}{\rotatebox{75}{$\feyn{a}$}}\!c\!\raisebox{1.5mm}{\rotatebox{-105}{$\feyn{a}$}} & \\
  \mbox{$\Sigma_{HF}(\mathbf{p}, \omega) = $ } & fs gv fs \ + \ fglS a f }$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like sometimes the "hacky" :-)...very niceeee. Can you tried to shift the arrows, a bit?

Comment: Me too! I have done a lot of weird things in the moment when I first learned TeX and stuck with them for wayyyy too long before finding the very easy improvement lol...

Comment: I did try to shift them vertically, but it didn't work out too well. I think it probably has the same underlying issue as the [origin = ] command. I'll take another hacky attempt at it though ;-)

Comment: For me it is very nice...but I can wait...:-)

Comment: I think that looks better now! Also, by moving things a bit more and rotating them carefully, I am sure you can get something even closer to the original image :-)